# How variable assignment and strict equality work in Javascript, in a little more depth

Tags: javascript, pass-by-reference, variable-assignment, equality, pass-by-value

We all know JS has *objects* and a group of *primitives*.

Let's examine the following assignments.

```
a = 'foo';
b = a;
c = 'foo'
a === b; //true
a = b = c = undefined;
```

The way I visualize the variable assignment process in JS for years now is like this.

- `a = 'foo';`

A new primitive string `foo` is created and added in a memory location. The variable `a` now points to that location in memory.

- `b = a`

The variable `b` points to the same location in memory as `a`, meaning it points to `foo`.

- `c = 'foo'`

The primitive string `foo` already exists in memory, so the variable `c` just points to that

- `a === b; //true`

The variables `a` and `b` are compared by reference, meaning the only thing that is checked is whether they point to the same location in memory and not if their values are the same. This means that no matter how long the strings, this should be a quick operation.

- `a = b = c = undefined`

The variables `a`, `b`, `c` all point to the primitive `undefined`. The primitive `foo` is not pointed at by any variables so it's garbage collected.

All the above should also apply to object properties.

I was 101% sure that this is how JS works, until today when I had a talk with a co-worker who was equally sure as me that when two variables are compared, even with a strict equality (`===`), they are *compared by value and not by reference*.

Hence, if we have to compare two variables that were both assigned a very very large string, e.g.

```
a = 'a huge string';
b = 'a huge string';
a === b; //true, takes 1ms
```

This equality check would take longer than if the two variables were just assigned a one letter string. e.g.

```
a = 'a small string';
b = 'a small string';
a === b; //true, takes 0.1ms
```

## In conclusion

Is any of my bullet points (my understanding) incorrect? Does strict equality compares values instead of reference?

Technical answers are welcomed and encouraged.

Thanks.

Comment: There's one important caveat to your assumptions. You are somewhat conflating individual JS engine implementation details with the official ECMAScript spec (not all of this behavior is outlined in the spec)

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, the main point is that strings and numbers are compared (and assigned for that matter) by value while objects (arrays, functions) are compared (and assigned) by reference.

Consider `var a = {}; var b = {}` but `a !== b`. As you showed, with strings they are equal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the [ECMAScript](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-strict-equality-comparison) spec, `===` compares values, not references, unless those values are objects.

For string comparison, they are compared lexicographically, as in checking if all chars are equal in the same order.

> If x and y are exactly the same sequence of code units (same length and same code units at corresponding indices), return true; otherwise, return false.

Here's the general algorithm for `a === b`:

```
// if both are undefined, return true
// if both are null, return true
// if both are numbers
//    if a is NaN, return false
//    if b is NaN, return false
//    if are equal numeric values, return true
//    if a is +0 and b is -0, return true
//    if b is +0 and a is -0, return true
//    return false
// if both are strings
//    if all chars equal and in the same order, return true
//    return false
// if both are booleans
//    if both are true or both are false, return true
//    return false
// if both are objects
//    if are equal references, return true
//    return false
// return false
```

I wrote a [small tool](https://nem035.github.io/js-equality-algorithms/) a while ago that demonstrates the `==` and `===` algorithm (as per the ES5 spec) that might help.

Now, as far as reusing memory from already defined strings, such as your example of `a = 'foo'` and `c = 'foo'` pointing to the same memory for efficiency reasons, that is an optimization that an engine can do to make things faster but is not part of the spec.

In fact, this is called [String Interning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning), and many languages do it.

Comment: This was certainly an eye opening answer, thanks for that. So, technically my co-worker was right :)

Comment: Well, again, it's a thin line between theory and practice :). In practice, most engines do string interning so I'd say you both need to define the judgment rules first before deciding who's right haha

Answer (score 2):

Whe you work with primitive types (Number, String, Boolean) you are comparing their values.

```
"string one" == "string one";  // true
3 == 3;  // true
false == false;  // true
```

Even undefined works similar:

```
undefined == undefined;  // true
```

The exception is NaN:

```
NaN == NaN;  // false
```

When you compare objects, you compare their references. For example:

```
var obj1 = { "name": "Charles" };
var obj2 = { "name": "Charles" };
obj1 == obj2;  // false
obj1 === obj2;  // false
```